# A way to "try" to click an Element without fail, if nonexistent (fire and forget) 

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-ide

I need a way to try to click on an element, but if it is not there, the test should not fail.
Kind of an "fire and forget" click.

I want to do that directly in Selenese (or js, as for *user-extensions.js*) , and not in PHPUnit/JUnit.

I thought maybe of a "user-extensions"-function to do this, so i searched the [openqa Site](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/SEL/Contributed%20User-Extensions) but i didn't find anything useful.

Update: My own first try: (not working)

```
Selenium.prototype.doClickAndForget= function(locator) {
    this.page().click(locator));
    return true;
};
```

Any Ideas on how to make it work?

Comment: I advise against this kind of test. It is better that your tests always do exactly the same thing each time, otherwise it makes debugging harder. If you are having problems with elements not being there due to AJAX etc., best to ask a separate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it with "storeEval()" and pure js.
Either i got a valid link or i returned a mandatory element to "fake klick" on, so sel will not throw any errors. 
Its a hack but i had "unpredefined" content on my site, so i needed a way to handle the possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can create a wrapper for `click(String)` method in `DefaultSelenium` like

```
public void clickWithoutFail(String locator){
    try{
        selenium.click(locator);
    }catch(SeleniumException ex){

    }
}
```

Above wrapper method may solve your problem. It will ignore any errors occured during click on non-existent element.

You can avoid having `try/catch` block by checking the presence of the locator using `isVisible()` method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your code is not js (which i need for _user-extension.js_), but i'll try to do that in js.